# Windows 11 - How to set Alt-Right+shift to the Hebrew keyboard?

Tags: windows-11, hebrew

Once, and I don't remember in what version it was changed, Left-Alt+Shift changed the keyboard to English and Right-Alt+Shift changed the keyboard to Hebrew.

Now in Windows 11 22H2 (build 22621.1413) this setting is gone and I cannot change the settings.

In the screenshot you can see that I can only set Left-Alt+Shift but not Right-Alt.

[image: Text Services and Input Languages]

Do you know of a way I can assign Right-Alt + Shift to a keyboard language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting that I have updated Windows to build 22621.1555 and now Alt Gr + Right Shift changes the keyboard to Hebrew without me doing anything else. It was probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The option to use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right Shift</kbd><kbd>[number]</kbd> is also missing from Windows 10, 21H2. BTW, note that it's not simply <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right Shift</kbd>,  but requires another character, e.g., number zero, in your screen shot.

However, use a third-party tool, such as [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or [Clavier+](https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/), to capture that key combination and call a PowerShell or CMD script [to change the active keyboard layout](https://powershell-guru.com/powershell-tip-87-set-keyboard-layout/) to Hebrew,

`Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList he-IL -Force`

and

`Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList en-US -Force`

to set it to English (US).

The `-Force` argument avoids having the dialog on screen.

BTW, I find the built-in keyboard shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> more convenient; each time it's pressed, it cycles through the list of available keyboards, with a popup to remind which is active. On the one hand, it's not *specific*, but with only two layouts, it's sufficient.

[image: Layout popup]

Comment: Thanks.

So now I have to learn how to create PowerShell scripts, name them and call them from another program? If that's what it takes, I will learn it.

Can't it be done by editing some values in the registry?

Comment: Either the two scripts given can be saved with PS1 extensions, and run by PowerShell, or you can change Registry entries... but they don't take effect until you log off and on again. BTW, I much prefer the built-in toggle, `Windows-Space`, which I'll add to the answer. חג שמח